# What exactly is [NSFetchedResultsController sections]?

Tags: core-data

I am really confused about this.

I see situations where [[NSFetchedResultsController sections] count] is used.
Then there are these situations, [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count].

Now i understand what the latter one is doing. that just makes sense to me.
But i don't understand the first one regarding the sections.

The document doesn't define sections. It actually defines it by using the term "sections" with its definition.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a `sectionNameKeyPath:` in the `initWithFetchRequest:...` call, then the fetched results controller will group the results into sections, corresponding to the sections of a table view.

So `[[NSFetchedResultsController sections] count]`is the number of sections and `[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]`is the total number of all fetched objects.

Comment: so by default I'm guessing the number of sections is just 1?

Comment: also, the concept of dividing fetches into sections using the initWithFetchRequest, this is like filtering? So if I want to retrieve all entities with a Name property that equals "Foo", then this is what i have to use to filter it?

Comment: It is not for filtering, but for grouping the rows into sections. Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451.

Comment: And yes, the default number of sections is 1.